# Colors in Terminal not working after deleting bash history

Tags: pantheon-terminal, color, default

I know it wasn't a good idea, but after I used the command

```
rm bash_history
```

in the pantheon terminal, the colors (like when using `ls`) disappeared.

What can I do?
Can someone provide the original `bash_history`file, or is there an easier way?

Note:
This

```
gsettings reset org.pantheon.terminal.settings palette
```

did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the file `/etc/skel/.bashrc` into your home. This is the default configuration for your bash profile, so it will reset the preferences.